# How do I set up pretty printing gdb 7.5

Tags: c++, gdb

I thought gdb 7.0 and higher has pretty printing included in it but I might be wrong? Can someone point me to the correct way to use this? Do I need to create a .gdbinit file for this? I tried copying one from stackoverload but it was giving me errors and then I read that pretty printing should be included in 7.0 and higher.  Can someone please school me on this?  When I print a vector I get the following, is there a way to get a better layout? The vector has data but it shows no data fields in the output below.

```
(gdb) p data
$4 = (std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > &) @0x7fffffffdfe0: {<std::_Vector_base<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >> = {
    _M_impl = {<std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, 
      _M_start = 0x6082d0, _M_finish = 0x6082d8, 
      _M_end_of_storage = 0x6082d8}}, <No data fields>}
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the following email works.  The thing I needed to do that I wasn't which wasn't apparent is that I needed to add the directory where the printers were installed to my path.

```
http://lists.kde.org/?l=kdevelop&m=125326438617051&w=2

(gdb) p data1
$1 = std::vector of length 8, capacity 8 = {"This is line", 
  "second item", "text 2 ", 
  "over 3", "lines", "", "", "last line."}
```